# How to determine first run of an app/How to allow file delete in app folder

Tags: file-permissions

I have an old VB6 app that I'm distributing with the PDW. I need to determine after installation if it's the first run of the app.  What's the simplest way to do this?

Currently, I install a dummy text file and use its existence as evidence of first run.  If firstrun.txt is in the app directory, I open a subroutine that creates some directories and copies some files and then deletes the txt file.  The next time, it skips the subroutine because firstrun.txt isn't there.  Works perfect until users get an error code 70 because they don't have the appropriate permission to delete the file.

This is the code I'm using to delete the text file:

```
mobjFSO.DeleteFile App.Path & "\firstrun.txt
```

Anyone have a better way?  Or could someone tell me how to allow the program to delete the file regardless of permisson?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the opposite approach.  If no file exists, assume it is the first run.  After the first run does its thing, write a file -- but write it to a user area, such as C:\Users\myuser\AppData on Windows.  This would be a more appropriate place to store this kind of data and you won't suffer the same permissions issues.

Comment: sometimes the simplest solution is right in front of your eyes...THANKS!